# Difficult Second Partial Derivative Where Variable of Differentiation is Difficult to Write

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have $k$ as a function of $t$ and $x$, and I know that
\begin{align}
d\tau &= dt-\left(\frac{1-k}{2}\right) \, dx \\
dr &= \left(\frac{1+k}{2}\right) \, dx
\end{align}
and I want to find $\dfrac{\partial^2x}{\partial r^2}$. Since I already know $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\dfrac{2}{1+k}$, does it work to say $$\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial r^2}=\frac{\partial (\frac{2}{1+k})}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial (\frac{2}{1+k})}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \quad ? $$
If not, how can I find it?

Comment: Your formula looks like a correct application of the chain rule.

Comment: This even applies when $x$ can't be written perfectly in terms of $\tau$ and $r$?

Comment: I think I assumed that $t, x$ and $\tau, r$ are in one to one corespondence, so that they both form coordinate systems. Otherwise what does $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ mean?

Comment: I was just thinking that since $k$ is explicitly in terms of $t$ and $x$, and looking at the relationships, attempting to write $k$ in terms of $r$ would add $k$ terms inside $k$, so I'm just not sure if the chain rule I did still works in that case. By the way, I found $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ from the Jacobi matrix. Technically, $\tau$ and $r$ are functions of both $t$ and $x$, if that answers your question about correspondence.

Comment: I assumed that the map $F(t, x) = (\tau(t, x), r(t, x))$ is a diffeomorphism. So $(\tau, r) = F(t, x)$ and $(t, x) = F^{-1}(\tau, r)$. Notation $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}$ when $r$ is not an independent variable means that there is a coordinate system $(r, r_1, \dots, r_k)$ and then $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial r}$ means you write $f$ in this system and take the ordinary partial with respect to $r$. The answer depends heavily on $r_1, \dots, r_k$ though.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: Tell me how you defined and computed $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$. I'm saying that this quantity depends on more things than just $x$ and $r$, so you have to be careful.

Comment: $dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr \rightarrow dx=\frac{2}{1+k}dr$

Comment: That isn't enough information. Are $(\tau, r)$ in one to one correspondence with $(t, x)$? If so, then you can write $dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\,dr + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau}\,d\tau$ as an equality of differential forms. Otherwise, $dx$ is not well defined.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. If you'd like, I can refer you to the precise page of the paper I got this from, to see if that can explain it better than I can.

Comment: Well, first I'll just tell you: These differentials are meant to transform the metric tensor $ds^2=-(dt-dx)(dt+kdx)$.

Comment: It seems very likely that $(\tau, r)$ and $(t, x)$ are both coordinate systems, but I would have to see your source to make sure. If this is the case, then your computation is correct, by the chain rule.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9702049

Comment: Page 13 of the document is where you'd want to look.